# How does SelectMany() work underneath, what algorithm does it use?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, collections

So i have this not so special method

```
public void FlagVoyageAsRemoved(int voyageId)
    {
        using (UnitOfWork uw = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            Voyage voyage = uw.VoyageRepository.FindSingle(v => v.VoyageId == voyageId,  
new string[] { "VoyageUsers.Costs" });
            List<Cost> userCosts = voyage.VoyageUsers.SelectMany(vu => vu.Costs).ToList();
//altough i am putting my items in a new list meaning its a new memory adress, the object tracker can still see them as part of the original collection, how come?
            costBl.FlagCostsAsDeleted(userCosts);
// these methods just change a proprety in each element of the collection, nothing more.
            costBl.FlagCostsAsDeleted(voyage.Costs);
            vUserBl.FlagVoyageUsersAsDeleted(voyage.VoyageUsers);
            voyage.HasDeleteFlag = true;
            uw.Commit();
        }
    }
```

My question is how do the new list elements can still be identified as part of the original collection, when using linq, or is this just something coming from the entity framework object tracker?

Comment: What do you mean by "the original collection"?

Comment: i mean the data retrieved in the first place. Example: Voyage.VoyageUsers.

Comment: OK, and how (and at which point in the code) did you notice that? You use `voyage.VoyageUsers`later on.

Comment: after i commit, altough i change the propreties of userCosts thats a new list with elements from the initial query, it updates them just fine without complaining that those objects are not recognized by the instance of UnitOfWork. (theoretically thats what it should do).

Comment: Well, the `Cost` records are identified by their own primary key. EF just updates them. It never needs the parents. You could have collected and updated them by by something like `context.Costs`. Or am I missing a point?

Comment: I dont think the identification is made using the primary key only, for each record there is an entity key, that is composed of the primary key and something else(cant remember) plus some tracking information. I am certain about it. (using EF 4.0)

Comment: Maybe you can update your question then with the part you don't remember right now. I wonder why it would make a difference whether the objects/records are updated when fetched through the parents or directly.

Comment: I disagree your assertion that userCosts is a new list.  It is just a reference to items in voyage.VoyageUsers.   There is no "new" in the line above.

Comment: does the extension method .ToList() not create a new list in wich it adds the new elements? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework keeps track of all the objects and collections it retrieves, so when you call `context.SaveChanges()` (and that is what I think is happening in your `uow.Commit()`method) it already know what to check.

Hope it helps.